# Internet Explorer 9 queryCommandValue('backColor') returns a number?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm just messing around with contenteditable property and while using queryCommandValue on backColor command, Internet Explorer 9 returns a number instead of rgb or hex color like in Chrome or Firefox.

For example using queryCommandValue on random text with background-color: rgb(255, 204, 0); returns 52479.

http://jsfiddle.net/Vu7Dk/12/

What could I do to force IE to return rgb color?

Comment: IE returns the hexacode as decimal: `0X00CCFF==52479`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting it with this function:

```
function toColor( input ) {
    if( typeof input != "number" ) {
        return input;
    }

    return "rgb(" + (input & 0xFF) + ", " +
                    ((input & 0xFF00) >> 8) + ", " +
                    ((input & 0xFF0000) >> 16 ) + ")";
}
//Usage
toColor(52479);
//"rgb(255, 204, 0)"
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/Vu7Dk/16/

Comment: @TadejMatek You can say thanks by accepting the answer. Press the checkmark on the left of my answer.